# How to use persistentStore(for: url) in core data Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to do the following:

Tap a cell of a `UITableView` cell then `segue` to the next `UIViewController` and display the database results. But there are multiple persistent stores therefore the designated store is specified by the cell label text.

The question is: How to use the method `persistentStore(for: url)`? Or is there some else way to specify a persistent store for the `fetchRequest`?

Here is my code that is not working:

```
func wordFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Word> {
    let fr = NSFetchRequest<Word>(entityName: "Word")
    fr.fetchBatchSize = 100

    // Assigning sort descriptors
    let firstLetterSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Word.firstLetter), ascending: true)
    let spellSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Word.spell), ascending: true)
    fr.sortDescriptors = [firstLetterSort, spellSort]

    // Get URL of the designated store to fetch
    let libname = (AppDelegate.nameDict as NSDictionary).allKeys(for: nameToFetch).first!

// I'm not sure the following line: which file should I use? I've tried
//.sqlite, .sqlite-shm and .sqlite-wal but none worked.
    let url = AppDelegate.coreDataStack.storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(libname).sqlite-wal")

    // Specify affected store for the fetch request
    var pss = [NSPersistentStore]()
    print(url)

// The following line fails:
    if let ps = coreDataStack.psc.persistentStore(for: url) {
        pss.append(ps)
    } else {

    }

    fr.affectedStores = pss
    print(fr.affectedStores ?? "No stores available.")
    return fr
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just curious hence asking, why dont you create separate managedObject contexts for each persistent store and run fetch request on corresponding managedObject context ???

Comment: Well, that seems like a good idea. But how so?

Comment: OK because the code can't be put as comment as its big enough I am adding as the answer :) If it works lemme know I'll keep it for future reference else I'll remove it as it should not mislead somebody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to deal with similar scenario where I had different persistent stores (to be specific one of type **NSInMemoryStoreType** and other of type **NSSQLiteStoreType** to be specific)

I found it easier to create separate **persistent store coordinators** for each store and create separate **managed object context** using these persistent stores as there **parent stores** :)

Here is the code which was written in iOS 9 swift 3, hence has older core data stack operations, I have seen iOS 10 Swift 3 Core data stack, I believe these methods can still give you idea of what am talking here :)

This is what you will see by default in Coredata stack, **getter** for  **persistentStoreCoordinator**

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
            log.debug(url)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
        catch{

        }
        return coordinator
    }()
```

Important statement here though is

```
try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
```

As you can see it specifies the persistent store type as Sqlite and specifies the configurationName as nil, which means default configuration :)

You can create multiple configurations in Coredata and specify there name in this statement to create separate persistent store coordinator for each configurations :)

You can have a look at my blog [Can core data be trusted with sensitive informations](https://learnwithmehere.blogspot.in/2016/09/can-core-data-be-trusted-with-sensitive.html) to see how you can create multiple configurations and stores :)

So lets assume you create another configuration and added entities to them and lets call it as "Test1" configuration, you will create a separate persistent store coordinator for that using,

```
lazy var test1PersistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: "Test1", at: url, options: nil)
        log.debug(url)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
    catch{

    }
    return coordinator
}()
```

Now you have two persistent store coordinators associated with two different configurations, simply create two managed object contexts using these persistent store coordinators as their parent store :)

```
   lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()


    lazy var managedObjectContextForBackTracking : NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let coordinator = self.test1PersistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()
```

Thats it :)

Now run your fetch requests on corresponding managedObject contexts :) and be sure that nothing messes up your core data :)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I will accept this now since your solution is at least the right path for me. Thank you.

Comment: This solution seems correct since at least I passed my code! Actually I've got another question for you that is kind of unrelated of this topic: --- Suppose you created a sqlite store (3 files of course) with another project with a model. And now you want to bundle that store with your CURRENT project that is a production. I can't read the store even if I created an exact same model. --- More specifically, the method loadPersistentStores() for my container doesn't load anything with the description specified by the store url.

Comment: @david-wu : Am not an expert in core data but I'll try my best to answer ur question buddy but before that lemme understand ur question properly, "And now you want to bundle that store with your CURRENT project that is a production." - by that you mean u are copying the core data model and core data stack code from your new project to the existing product and making a build ?? If yes and if you still have an issue, have you clearly read all the core data stack methods and make changes to them like name of the  sqlite file, its location, type of store specific to your production project ?

Comment: Have you enabled core data in your production project ?? If no try enabling it, If its enabled still have issue try re generating the core data entity models, try putting break point in core data stack methods like getter of managedObject context, persistent store and verify if they are being called and working properly :) I have never tried anything like this before so just guessing. Lemme know whats ur observation after this :) Hope u'll solve it soon :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply. It turned out that I made a slight change in the product project that made the model incompatible with the store created by another project. Even if the change in the model has nothing to do with the existing data columns, the model has to be exactly the same! Therefore it was my own mistake and after correcting it worked fine -- we can indeed read stores created by other projects provided that all have same model.

Comment: @david-wu : Am glad you solved it buddy :) Happy coding :)